# Advice/Guidance - composer/beam/dataflow on gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to learn/try out cloud composer/beam/dataflow on gcp.

I have written functions to do some basic cleaning of data in python, and used a DAG in cloud composer to run this function to download a file from a bucket, process it, and upload it to a bucket at a set frequency.

It was all bespoke written functionality. I am now trying to figure out how I use beam pipeline and data flow instead and use cloud composer to kick off the dataflow job.

The cleaning I am trying to do, is take a csv input of col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 and combine the middle 3 columns to output a csv of col1,combinedcol234,col5.

Questions I have are...

- How do I pull in my own functions within a beam pipeline to do this merge?
- Should I be pulling in my own functions or do beam have built in ways of doing this?
- How do I then trigger a pipeline from a dag?
- Does anyone have any example code on git hub?

I have been googling and trying to research but can't seem to find anything that helps me get my head around it enough.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator` to run a dataflow job in a python.

- You have to instantiate your cloud composer environment;
- Add the dataflow job file in a bucket;
- Add the input file to a bucket;
- Add the following dag in the `DAGs` directory of the composer environment:

`composer_dataflow_dag.py`:

```py
import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataflow import DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

bucket_path = "gs://<bucket name>"
project_id = "<project name>"
gce_zone = "us-central1-a"
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
tstmp = datetime.datetime.now(tz).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

default_args = {
    # Tell airflow to start one day ago, so that it runs as soon as you upload it
    "start_date": days_ago(1),
    "dataflow_default_options": {
        "project": project_id,
        # Set to your zone
        "zone": gce_zone,
        # This is a subfolder for storing temporary files, like the staged pipeline job.
        "tempLocation": bucket_path + "/tmp/",
    },
}


with models.DAG(
    "composer_dataflow_dag",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),  # Override to match your needs
) as dag:

    create_mastertable = DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator(
        task_id="create_mastertable",
        py_file=f'gs://<bucket name>/dataflow-job.py',
        options={"runner":"DataflowRunner","project":project_id,"region":"us-central1" ,"temp_location":"gs://<bucket name>/", "staging_location":"gs://<bucket name>/"},
        job_name=f'job{tstmp}',
        location='us-central1',
        wait_until_finished=True,
    )
```

Here is the dataflow job file, with the modification you want to concatenate some columns data:

`dataflow-job.py`

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
tstmp = datetime.now(tz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

bucket_path = "gs://<bucket>"
input_file = f'{bucket_path}/inputFile.txt'
output = f'{bucket_path}/output_{tstmp}.txt'


p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions())

( p | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file, skip_header_lines=1)
    | beam.Map(lambda x:x.split(","))
     | beam.Map(lambda x:f'{x[0]},{x[1]}{x[2]}{x[3]},{x[4]}')
     | beam.io.WriteToText(output) )

p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

After running the result will be stored in the gcs Bucket:
[image]

[image]

Comment: This an amazing amount of detail. Thank you, I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: If a one of the columns I wish to combine are either blank, null or N/A is there a way to remove them?

Comment: You can use the following in the beam map: `f'{x[0]},{x[1] if (x[1] != None and x[1] != "N/A") else ""},{x[2]}'`

Answer (score 0):

A beam program is just an ordinary Python program that builds up a pipeline and runs it. For example

'''
def main():
with beam.Pipline() as p:
p | beam.io.ReadFromText(...) | beam.Map(...) | beam.io.WriteToText(...)
'''

Many [examples](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples) can be found in the repository and the [programming guide is useful too](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples)https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/ . The easiest way to read CSV files is with the [dataframes API](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) which retruns an object you can manipulate as if it were a Pandas Dataframe, or you can turn [into a PCollection](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/#embedding-dataframes-in-a-pipeline) (where each column is an attribute of a named tuple) and process with Beam's [Map, FlatMap, etc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/overview/), e.g.

```
pcoll | beam.Map(
    lambda row: (row.col1, func(row.col2, row.col3, row.col4), row.col5)))
```